# Как отправить Facebook сообщение но не показывать изображение в блоке шаринга

Tags: веб-программирование, facebook, facebook-api, share, sendmessage

Используем авторизацию Facebook для пользователей сайта и хотим использовать фичу по отправке личного сообщения от имени зарегистрированного пользователя его Facebook другу используя страндартное окно "Send Message".

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://www.site.com/link/to/page',
});
```

На http://www.site.com/link/to/page проставляем мета-теги

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="(*pagelink)" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="SiteName" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Your new nomination" />
```

А вот с для картинки пробовали не ставить тег og:image (тогда FB берет первую попавшеюся картинку на странице), подставлять в тег пустую строку, картину в один пиксель (в таком случае FB выдает ошибку и редиректится на главную страницу, откуда и берет текст и картинку)

```
<meta property=""              content="" />
<meta property=""              content="(*imagelink)" />
```

Самое интересное, что на ранних стадиях разработки у нас получалось не выводить такие картинки, видимо Facebook ничего не находил и сообщения уходили в нужном нам виде.

Сейчас же как ми не стараемся, мы не можем заблокировать такие изображения - Facebook сам подставляет что посчитает нужным для иллюстрации, иногда получается довольно забавно.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как принудительно отключить картинку при отправке сообщения таким образом?

Comment: Картинки лучше прикладывать к вопросу.